# How set up remote npm authentication with Artifactory

Tags: npm, artifactory, verdaccio, sinopia

I have a downstream Sinopia repository, that requires authentication, that I want to set up as a remote npm repo in Artifactory.  How do I provide Artifactory the credentials for the remote?

Answer (score 2):

For remote authentication Artifactory only supports Basic authentication. If Sinopoa supports Basic, you can define your sinopia credentials under Admin -> Repositories -> Remote -> edit your remote repo -> fill in your credentials under the Advanced tab.

Comment: Yes I tried that and it doesn't work.  It doesn't pass the credentials at all to the remote repository.

Comment: What makes you think that it doesn't? I'm not very familiar with Sinopia but I just set it up with some private package, and while it fails without credentials, it does succeed as soon as I put the credentials in the remote repo. You can verify that Artifactory does send the "Authorization: Basic ..." header by adding the http.wire logger to your $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc/logback.xml:                                               <logger name="org.apache.http.wire">
        <level value="debug"/>
    </logger>

Comment: @leepowell not in this case.  The only case we got working was from artifactory to artifactory